# Observing Constructible StyleSheets changes

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I have the following code snippet which uses Constructible Stylesheets. (when clicking on the button the attached constructible stylesheet is updated with a random color).

How do I observe and listen to this changes? (I would like to capture the computed style changes on the element, or alternatively - the updated constructible stylesheet)

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");


var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  let text = "";
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    text += "changed " + mutation.attributeName;
  });
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += `<div>${text}</div>`;
});

var observerConfig = {
  attributes: true
};

var targetNode = document.getElementById("div1");

document.getElementById("btnAttachStyleSheet").addEventListener("click", () => {
  switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)) {
    case 1:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:blue}");
      break;
    case 2:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:yellow}");
      break;
    case 3:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:green}");
      break;
    case 4:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:brown}");
      break;
    default:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:pink}");
  }
});
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
observer.observe(targetNode, observerConfig);
```

```html
<h1>Adopted stylesheets</h1>
<button id="btnAttachStyleSheet">Update style sheet</button>
<div style="padding: 1rem;" id="div1" class="color">colored div</div>

<h3>mutations:</h3>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I just tried to ran this on Firefox 78.4.1 esr and it did not ran. After a bit of research I found that constructible stylesheets are only supported in Chomre version 73 onwards. Other browsers have not implemented this spec yet. Here's the details for browser support: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5394843094220800. I only mention this because if there's not widespread support for this, you may consider other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification for [`replaceSync`](https://wicg.github.io/construct-stylesheets/#dom-cssstylesheet-replacesync) doesn't mention triggering any events. It's not a DOM mutation, so you can't watch for it with a `MutationObserver.

Instead, if you control the code calling `replaceSync`, call your own function that does `replaceSync` and then raises an event specific to your code (and similarly for `replace`):

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

var targetNode = document.getElementById("div1");

document.getElementById("btnAttachStyleSheet").addEventListener("click", () => {
  switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)) {
    case 1:
      sheetReplaceSync(sheet, ".color {color:blue}");
      break;
    case 2:
      sheetReplaceSync(sheet, ".color {color:yellow}");
      break;
    case 3:
      sheetReplaceSync(sheet, ".color {color:green}");
      break;
    case 4:
      sheetReplaceSync(sheet, ".color {color:brown}");
      break;
    default:
      sheetReplaceSync(sheet, ".color {color:pink}");
  }
});
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
function sheetReplaceSync(sheet, ...args) {
    const result = sheet.replaceSync(...args);
    console.log("Changed!");
    return result;
}
function sheetReplace(sheet, ...args) {
    return sheet.replace(...args).then(result => {
        console.log("Changed!");
        return result;
    });
};
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
```

```html
<h1>Adopted stylesheets</h1>
<button id="btnAttachStyleSheet">Update style sheet</button>
<div style="padding: 1rem;" id="div1" class="color">colored div</div>
<h3>mutations:</h3>
<div id="output"></div>
```

If you don't control the code calling `replaceSync`, you could replace the method (and `replace`) on the sheet to tap into it, but I'd avoid that if possible:

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

var targetNode = document.getElementById("div1");

document.getElementById("btnAttachStyleSheet").addEventListener("click", () => {
  switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)) {
    case 1:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:blue}");
      break;
    case 2:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:yellow}");
      break;
    case 3:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:green}");
      break;
    case 4:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:brown}");
      break;
    default:
      sheet.replaceSync(".color {color:pink}");
  }
});
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
const replaceSync = sheet.replaceSync;
const replace = sheet.replace;
sheet.replaceSync = function(...args) {
    const result = replaceSync.call(this, ...args);
    console.log("Changed!");
    return result;
};
sheet.replace = function(...args) {
    return replace.call(this, ...args).then(result => {
        console.log("Changed!");
        return result;
    });
};
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
```

```html
<h1>Adopted stylesheets</h1>
<button id="btnAttachStyleSheet">Update style sheet</button>
<div style="padding: 1rem;" id="div1" class="color">colored div</div>
<h3>mutations:</h3>
<div id="output"></div>
```